# Why the pointer lose its reference when I pass an array as a function argument? C

Tags: c

my problem is that having this code:

```
int size=4384;
char buffer[size];
codifyDHCPmessage(buffer, message, size);
```

where message is an struct which only contains char[], and the function return in buffer, all the fields from the struct.

I test it going through the buffer array, and checking that all the fields are ok.

But my problem is that if i pass again that buffer into a new function as:

```
decodifyDHCPmessage(buffer,messageAux, size);
```

the first thing I do in that function is to check the size of buffer, which only tells me that is 4, when it's suppossed to be 4384.... and I don't know why.

I have to tell that I'm not an expert in C, and the pointer, and memory allocation issues are hard for me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show us the prototypes of the functions!

Comment: void codifyDHCPmessage(char buffer[], struct DHCP message, int size);
void decodifyDHCPmessage(char buffer[],struct DHCP, int size);

Comment: @RMartinho Wrong language … OP’s code isn’t even valid C++.

Comment: You are anyways passing the size argument also? So why again sizeof? Do you want to know the amount of **characters** filled in the buffer?

Comment: @PavanManjunath yeah it was because of that. But I sorted it out thanks for Konrad Rudolph answer.

Comment: nice to hear your problem is solved :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph dammit, I didn't even notice there were **four** language tags on this :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your function signature looks like this:

```
void codifyDHCPmessage(char[], message_t, size_t);
```

(or similar)

The problem is that `[]` in a function signature really means `*`, that is, `char[]` is really `char*`. In other words, the array argument decays to a pointer whose size is, unsurprisingly, 4.

As far as I know (but I could be wrong …), C doesn’t allow you to pass arrays into functions at all, it just supports pointers. That’s why you need to pass the size as an explicit separate argument.

Comment: But I have seen that I lose the information in the first position of the array inside the decodify function, why? I can't recover the buffer[0] position correctly, the other one yes.

Comment: @Joe Nothing in the code you posted would cause that. Obviously you are doing *something else*. This is why it’s so important that you post a **complete, minimal** working example that demonstrates the problem. The code, as it is, works. And the issue you described in the question (rather than in the comment) is correctly explained by my answer.

Comment: You are completely right, it was my mistake not to post a piece of code more to see this last error. But I solved it, thank you very much for your answers help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Static stack arrays 'decay' into plain old pointers when passed as arguments into functions. What then happens, is using `sizeof` gets the size of the pointer, not the array. You'll need to pass the array size as another argument.

Answer (score 3):

When an array is passed to a function, **actually the pointer to it base address is passed**. Now if you apply `sizeof` over it, it returns only 4, the sizeof a pointer on 32-bit systems.

If you really want the number of characters in `buffer`, you need to make sure it is null terminated before passing it and then in the called function, use something like `strlen` to calculate the size or you have to calculate the array size in the caller itself (where the array is defined and `sizeof` works fine on it)and then send it to the function to be called.

You are already sending the size of the array as an argument. **But if want to the know the *actual* number of characters inside the array**, then you can do something like this-

```
int size=4384;
char buffer[size];
memset(buffer, 0, size);
```

And then call your `codifyDHCPmessage`.Finally, inside `decodifyDHCPmessage` you can do

```
unsigned sz = strlen(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ the buffer  argument is passed to a function as a pointer==> it retuns you the sizeof pointer in bytes - 4.

Comment: No, `buffer` is *not* a pointer, it’s an array. `sizeof buffer` will yield 4384, not 4.

Comment: That's not quite correct; as Konrad said, `buffer` is an array, but arrays can't be passed as arguments, so the pointer to the start of the array is passed as the argument instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - array argument is passed to a function as a pointer .

Comment: @Yakov But that’s not what you wrote.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - it what I meant and it is the same answer Pavan Manjunath gave.

Comment: @Yakov That’s nice but your answer is still wrong. There is clearly a difference between what you *meant* and what you *wrote*.